# How to find minimum Hamming distance of concatenated two encoded words?

Tags: coding-theory

> Given data word $M$ of $2n$ bits $M$ is split into 2 words $M_1M_2$ whereas the length of $M_1$ is $n$ bits as well as the length of $M_2$ is also $n$ bits. $M_1$ and $M_2$ are encoded separately using Hamming code and result in words $K_1$ and $K_2$ respectively. The final result is the concatenation of $K_1$ and $K_2$ that is $K_1K_2$. What is the minimal Hamming distance of the code?

In general a code is said to be $k$ error detecting if, and only if, the minimum Hamming distance between any two of its codewords is at least $k+1$. But we're not given how many errors the code detects. So if the code detects only $1$ error than the minimal Hamming distance is $2$. But this is relevant for any code? How to do the given parameters come into play?

Comment: I don't think Hamming codes deserve their own tag even though they are nice.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ...and even if they *do* deserve their own tag, it is customary to discuss the introduction of new tags in the [Tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31103/tag-management-2020) before creating a new tag.

Comment: This problem is equivalent to ask what is the minimum Hamming distance of the following coding scheme: we encode two independent messages using two identical Hamming codes. For this coding scheme, the minimum Hamming distance is the same as that coding for only one message, which is $3$ since Hamming code is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the blocks of the code are not of length $2n$ ($M$), they are of length $n$ ($M_1,M_2$), as the Hamming code is applied to each half separately. Thus the minimal Hamming distance between two words in the concatenated code is equal to that for just one of the halves, which is therefore $3$ *since Hamming codes were used*.

Comment: But why is the minimal Hamming distance (MHD) just $3$? When we compare $K_iK_j$ to $K_gK_h$ 6 errors could be  detected in total

Comment: @Yos I could just change $M_1$ to another message so that the new codeword $K_1$ has a Hamming distance of $3$ from the old $K_1$; $M_2$ and $K_2$ remain unchanged.

Comment: and $3$ is the minimal distance in general because the first and second bits are used as check bits right?

Comment: @Yos It's just a fundamental property of Hamming codes that their Hamming distance is $3$ no matter the length. (It is _extended_ Hamming codes that have minimal distance $4$.)